How do I route some of the USB ports on this Lenovo ideacentre 510S-07ICB motherboard to the USB ports on this Fractal Design Define 7 XL case?
I have a motherboard for a Lenovo ideacentre 510S-07ICB and I want to mount it in a Fractal Design 7 XL case (don't ask - it's what I have to deal with ) but I don't know if it's possible to wire up the USB from the front of the board to the front of the case.
The ideacentre has USB 2 USB 3.1 Gen 1 ports and two USB 3.1 Gen 2 ports on its front side. Here's what that looks like. Here's a view of the pinout from the bottom (Note that both of those pictures are from eBay, I haven't unmounted my board yet. Here's a link to the platform specification. )
The Define has one USB 3.1 Gen 2 Type-C port, two "USB 3.0" ports and two USB 2.0 ports.
It looks like this and it's connected like this.
How do I bridge this gap? How do I go from female USB-A to USB 3.0 and USB 3.1 Gen2 headers? Will cables with USB-A to those kinds of headers work? Are they any good or will they limit my bandwidth and power? If not, then do I need to de-solder the two connectors and put my own pin headers on? I'd really love to avoid that. Is that even possible based on how the pins are laid out?
For example, I found this one for USB 3.0. Here's one for USB 3.1 Gen2. Are these any good? What exactly should I be searching for? I barely found these two. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place, but I didn't find much on DigiKey either.

This might be better asked at https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ .
